# CoreData: filter results comparing same attribute of the entity

Tags: core-data

I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the same results I'm get with SQL.

I have this situation:

Table A:
id
name (String)

Table B:
origin (foreign key)
special (boolean)
price (decimal)

Table A <->> Table B

In SQL I do:

Select * FROM A as a left JOIN B as b1 on a.id = b1.origin LEFT JOIN B as b2 on a.id = b2.origin WHERE b1.special = true and b1.special <> b2.special and b1.price < b2.price

This query finds all occurrences of B where a special has a lower price than a "regular" one.

Is there a way to create such filter in Core Data (NSPredicate or anything else?)?

Thanks,
Giorgio

**EDIT:**

I have an entity (Cards) with a relationship one to many with  another entity (CardType). Cards have generic infos, such name, category, imageUrl, while CardType has all the deatils: price, quantity, language, condition and special.

**Example:**

**Card**:"TestCard", "FirstSet", "http://..." *(name, category, imageUrl)*

**CardType1**: 10.0, 150, "EN", "Good", false *(price, quantity, language, condition and special)*

**CardType2**: 8.0, 20, "EN", "Good", true

**CardType3**: 7.5, 30, "IT", "Poor", false

What I want to do, is find all CardTypes where the price of a special one with same language and condition is lower than a regular (not special) one. In this example, I'm expecting CardType2.

Let me know if it's clear now. Thank you all!

Comment: Could we have a short (~5 line) data sample with desired result?

Comment: You should stop thinking of core data as an sql database so you don’t need a foreign key for instance and it’s not about tables and rows but about model classes and instances. You should also try to explain a little better what the predicate should do, the current description looks incorrect to me.

Comment: I've added an example